# VBA's ASC() function returning random values for special characters, only on my machine

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When running this piece of VBA code on my colleagues computers, the value of `temp` is 176.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim temp as Integer
    temp = ASC("°")
End Sub
```

This is appopriate, [since this is the ASCII value of °](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0#:%7E:text=Inserting%20ASCII%20characters&text=For%20example%2C%20to%20insert%20the,0176%20on%20the%20numeric%20keypad.).

On my machine, I end up with a totally different value. Which changes when I restart the computer and/or Microsoft Excel. Sometimes I have 64, sometimes I have 232.

Things I tried :

- 'Repair' Microsoft Excel
- Reinstall Microsoft Office from scratch

Why is this piece of code failing on my machine ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because ° is part of the **extended** ASCII table.

Maybe [ASC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/asc-function) was meant to consistently support characters in this range (even if this is not clearly stated in the docs).

However, I could observe the return value getting consistent after **Disabling Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support**.

This checkbox is located under Settings > All Settings > Time & Language > Language > Administrative Language Settings

Comment: Perhaps it is related to an incompatibility between the VBE/Excel and UTF-8 support.